# How do I move all docker containers, volumes, images etc from a system that I'm unable to boot to a new host

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm on Ubuntu-server 20.04 and the old system was Arch Linux, both running on identical hardware (it's the same machine)

I have the filesystem mounted (at /mnt if it helps)

I have googled but all the links I come across are for systems that are still running. I have managed to totally bork my previous install so that is out of the question.

Any assistance would be wonderful

Comment: If the new host can't boot, then you'll need to fix that first right?

Comment: No the new host can boot. The old install can't. I'm sorry if that wasn't clear @Martheen

Comment: Edit your title and question to clarify that.